VertexAI quota limit
I want to setup my Google Cloud VertexAI environment such that if I use more than 1000$ the environment automatically shuts down and prevents me from using it. I am unable to find a quota limit for this.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about doing this ?
I wrote a job that checks the spend several times a day and simply deletes the project. But its only a workaround.

Maybe something like this would work?

You create a pub sub topic.
You set up budget notifications and publish them to the pub sub topic-
You create a Cloud Function that its trigger by a topic notification with a code that detaches the billing account from said project-

